# installing Xmgrace in MAC OS

Tags: mac, xorg, osx-el-capitan

I am trying to use [xmgrace](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/) in Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.6). But every time i try to open it shows following error

```
Warning: Widget must be a VendorShell.
Warning: Fatal Error: 
_XmGetDefaultDisplay cannot be used prior to VendorS.Initialize, returns NULL

Oops! Got SIGSYS

Please use "Help/Comments" to report the bug.
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is still relevant. I fond the solution on homebrew github.

The solution is [taken from this thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-x11/issues/255):

As a workaround, to get motif-based programs running again:

Downgrade XQuartz to 2.7.8

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Re-install openmotif and the affected programs from source

The source of error [taken from this thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1189):

So this was probably caused by XQuartz being upgraded on the test-bot servers. I suspect the first time that an openmotif bottle was built against 2.7.9, it linked to the two-level-namespace libXt.7.dylib, and @ltbuchman picked it up on a subsequent update.

Aha! The 2.7.10_rc4 release notes even have an item about libXt and Motif. They say:

```
libXt
libXt.6.dylib is now a two-level-namespace dylib
libXt.7.dylib is now a stub dylib that re-exports libXt.6.dylib (for binary compatibility with anything built against XQuartz 2.7.9)
A flat_namespace version of libXt is available in /opt/X11/lib/flat_namespace to help ease the transition (#96292)
Set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/flat_namespace when executing older non-compliant software (eg: Motif-based applications)
Motif users are encouraged to file bugs against Motif to encourage them to fix that library.
```

And this from the XQuartz 2.7.9 release notes:

```
libXt
No longer linked with -flat_namespace
Binary compatibility maintained for existing clients of libXt.6.dylib
```

Which I think means that libXt.6.dylib is -flat_namespace, and the new libXt.7.dylib is not.

Here's the library from XQuartz 2.7.8 (the prior version):

```
$ otool -hv libXt.6.dylib
libXt.6.dylib:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64  X86_64        ALL  0x00       DYLIB    19       2024 DYLDLINK NO_REEXPORTED_DYLIBS APP_EXTENSION_SAFE
Note the lack of TWOLEVEL in the flags. There is no libXt.7.dylib in this version.
```

Here's the libs from XQuartz 2.7.9:

```
$ otool -hv libXt.6.dylib libXt.7.dylib
libXt.6.dylib:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64  X86_64        ALL  0x00       DYLIB    19       2024 DYLDLINK NO_REEXPORTED_DYLIBS APP_EXTENSION_SAFE
libXt.7.dylib:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64  X86_64        ALL  0x00       DYLIB    19       2024   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL NO_REEXPORTED_DYLIBS APP_EXTENSION_SAFE
```